# Is there a way to adjust font size by screen width in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen a lot of posts on how to adjust font-size using media queries for different devices. But is there is way to make the font bigger or smaller solely based on how wide your screen is? So if you shrink your browser window to the narrowest possible width, the font size would be small but font size would be big if you maximize your window.

Comment: How about using mediaQueries?

Comment: Well, for me at least, it seems that media queries don't work for when I simply maximize or minimize my browser window.

Comment: Well that depends on the media query and if the browser supports media-queries, this should work in all modern browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/x3u3bafv/

Comment: In Bootstrsap it is already or automatically working, a large text will be large on large screen and on small screen also large but smaller than large screen.

Comment: axel.michel, your jsfiddle really helped! Is there a way I can mark your answer as most helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an additional library, I prefer using: viewport, media query, and a font size that is adjusted based on the screen size.

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```

The css:

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    .image-thumbnail > p{
        font-size: 3.0vw;
    }
}
```

CSS-Tricks has more about this technique: [Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 

### Flowtype.js

It will make your font **responsive**.